# how to read property files values from different properties (for eg - prop1_dev,prop2_stage,prop3_prod) in mule

Tags: mulesoft

Suppose I am passing prop1 and dev through path parameter,and want to read the values as per my path params. Here 2 values are getting changed to read one particular property file.
In each property file i have one variable which i want to read as per my path parameter.
for eg -  `prop1_dev.properties,prop2_stage.properties,prop3_prod.properties`

Answer (score 0):

You can use ${} syntax to retrieve environment variables set as arguments etc. You can build up the path to the properties file using multiple environement variables like so:

For:

```
-Denv=dev -DotherProp=prop1
```

Mule Config:

```
<configuration-properties file="${otherProp}_${env}-properties.yaml" />
```

Would load the file: `prop1_dev.properties`